# Translation of "You are a good doctor"

Tags: traduction, pronoms, articles, professions

Normally, professions are used [without article](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14290/why-do-professions-have-no-article-when-used-after-%C3%AAtre) when using the verb *être*:

> Il/Elle est médecin.

However, I've read that when the profession is modified, the pronoun *il/elle* should be replaced by *ce*:

> C'est un bon médecin. (**Not**: Il/Elle est un bon médecin.)

So how can I say the following in French?

> You are a good doctor.

According to the rules above, saying "Vous êtes un bon médecin" would be wrong. But saying "C'est un bon médecin" doesn't sound right in this case either.

Similarly, how could one say "I am a good doctor"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pronoun *ce/c'/ç'* can only be a 3rd person subject, it can only replace *she/he/it/they/this/that* (and not in all cases, you might find [this post](http://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/cest-versus-il-elle-est) interesting).
In all other cases you must use the usual subject pronoun.

> Vous êtes /tu es / je suis /un bon médecin.