# Why is an indefinite article (a) omitted in "Il continue d'être mauvais garçon"?

Tags: grammaire, articles, adjectifs-indefinis

In the following sentence:

> Il continue d'être mauvais garçon.

The English sentence is as follows:

> He continues to be a bad boy.

This sentence lacks an indefinite article *a* for a noun *garçon*.

However, I learned that in French, you need an article before any nouns. Why does this sentence lack it and when can I omit it grammartically?

Answer (score 2):

Articles are not always required before nouns. There are actually many cases where they are either not used or optional.

In that case (attribute to a person), the indefinite article is optional so you can write either:

> Il continue d'être mauvais garçon.

or

> Il continue d'être un mauvais garçon.

See also:

- [*Cas d’absence d’article en français : difficultés des
  apprenants et proposition d’une analyse unifiée*, 
  Lidia Lebas-Fraczak](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00749285/document), a paper showing many examples of such cases.
- [Il est/c'est un bon avocat](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24536/il-est-cest-un-bon-avocat)

Answer (score 0):

L'analyse suivante est très probablement loin de prendre en compte tous les cas possibles et de même un peu incertaine quant à  faire cela très précisément pour ceux qui ont été relevés, mais elle semble préférable à rien du tout pour un début, lequel inspirera peu être quelqu'un dans le sens de fournir quelque chose de meilleur.

L'article indéfini peut être omis dans les cas où le groupe nominal satisfait aux critères suivants.

Le GN décrit une personne.

> L'activité que le nom implique est  institution.

- barman, épicier, professeur, ouvrier, président, détaillant, gendarme, militaire, marin, prêtre, chevalier de la légion d'honneur, député,

Avec les présentatifs (c'est, voilà…) l'article est nécessaire.

- C'est un ouvrier. _ Voilà un gendarme.

ARTICLE NÉCESSAIRE (parce que pas d'institution) : nageur, marcheur, vagabond, mari, époux,  mélomane (sans art. pris comme adj.), paria, reclus, voleur, tueur, assassin, parricide

Ceci est vrai pour la majorité des constructions ; cependant certains arrangements ne prennent pas d'article.

- Jean Bressel est un assassin et il le restera. _ Assassin, il est et assassin, il restera.

> Le GN comprends un nom et un adj. et il a acquis un statut d'unité plus ou moins définie qui tend à endosser un statut adjectival.

- (un) mauvais garçon, (un) bon enfant, (un) mauvais cheval, (une) tête de cochon, (une) partie prenante,

Exception : enfant terrible

ARTICLE NÉCESSAIRE (pas une unité prédéfinie) : jeune garçon, petit garçon, cancre inné, enfant précoce, femme âgée, élément dissipé,…