# « Tu disais être imbécile » ou « Tu disais être un imbécile »?

Tags: usage, articles

L’article indéfini « un » est-il facultatif ou obligatoire, voire carrément superflu?

Comment: C'est très soutenu. Dans la vie courante : **Tu disais qu't'étais un idiot.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Premièrement, « imbécile » est un mot qui est à la fois un adjectif et un substantif.

Dans la forme avec un article, « tu disais être un imbécile », c'est clairement le substantif qui est utilisé, les adjectifs ne prenant jamais un article.

Dans la forme sans l'article, « tu disais être imbécile », c'est moins clair. En effet, l'usage de noms sans article à cette position est un tour connu ([voir cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/14290/176) par exemple). Mais « imbécile » ne me semble pas faire partie d'une catégorie de noms pour lequel le tour existe, en effet « tu disais être génie » ne me semble pas être correct. Donc dans cet usage c'est bien un adjectif.

Pour les mots qui auraient des acceptions comme adjectifs et substantifs plus différentes qu'« imbécile », il y aurait donc une différence de sens entre les deux formes. Même dans le cas d'« imbécile » ou les sens sont proches, il me semble avoir une nuance entre les deux formes, mais je n'arrive pas à l'expliciter ni même à savoir si elle est due au mot ou au tour.

Answer (score 0):

Non locuteur natif mais je dirais

> Tu disais être un imbécile.

À noter que la première tournure n'est pas nécessairement gauche.

Voir aussi le [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%AAtre%20imb%C3%A9cile%2C%20%C3%AAtre%20un%20imb%C3%A9cile&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%AAtre%20imb%C3%A9cile%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%AAtre%20un%20imb%C3%A9cile%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 0):

« Imbécile » est un nom et un adjectif, par conséquent selon qu'il est utilisé comme un nom « Un imbécile grille le feu rouge » ou comme un adjectif « Un homme, imbécile, grille le feu rouge » ; les deux cas d'utilisation sont corrects.